# How Do I Get the Code Analysis Window without Committing Changes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ (for Java), pressing the `Commit Changes` button provides a checkbox for performing code analysis. When I check this box and it finds issues, it gives me a very different window than the one I get when I use `Analyze` -> `Inspect Code`. Is there a way to perform code analysis in exactly the same way the `Commit Changes` button does?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to access this view outside of the commit dialog.

Comment: Is there some way to make sure the code is clean and `Commit Changes` won't surprise me with more issues?

Comment: Why doesn't the regular Analyze | Inspect Code serve this purpose for you?

Comment: Is it known to be a superset? It seems to look for different issues.